# ABCD is a cyclic quadrilateral whose diagonals intersect at point P.

Tags: geometry, contest-math, circles, quadrilateral

$ABCD$ is a cyclic quadrilateral whose diagonals intersect at point $P$. Let the centres of the circumcircles of $ABCD$, $\triangle ABP$, $\triangle BCP$, $\triangle CDP$, $\triangle DAP$ be $O$, $O$<sub>$1$</sub>, $O$<sub>$2$</sub>, $O$<sub>$3$</sub>, $O$<sub>$4$</sub> in the given order. Prove that $OP$, $O$<sub>$1$</sub>$O$<sub>$3$</sub>, $O$<sub>$2$</sub>$O$<sub>$4$</sub> intersect at one point.

[image: This is the graph.]

By connecting $O$<sub>$1$</sub>, $O$<sub>$2$</sub>, $O$<sub>$3$</sub>, $O$<sub>$4$</sub>, we can see that $O$<sub>$1$</sub>$O$<sub>$2$</sub> is perpendicular to common cord $BP$. Similarly, $O$<sub>$3$</sub>$O$<sub>$4$</sub> is perpendicular to common cord $DP$.

Since $D$, $P$, and $B$ are on the same line; $O$<sub>$1$</sub>$O$<sub>$2$</sub> is parallel to $O$<sub>$3$</sub>$O$<sub>$4$</sub>. Similarly, $O$<sub>$1$</sub>$O$<sub>$4$</sub> is parallel to $O$<sub>$2$</sub>$O$<sub>$3$</sub>.
So, $O$<sub>$1$</sub>$O$<sub>$2$</sub>$O$<sub>$3$</sub>$O$<sub>$4$</sub> is a parallelogram

Comment: Please provide "context" for the question. A copy+pasted problem is not enough, try to give details and framework for the question. Which are the own attempts to solve the problem? Which is the level, the source? A picture would be a minimal ingredient to show a first step. It is the way it works...

Comment: Wonderful picture, and good adds... Let us now considert the mid point of $OP$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider the inversion $*$ with center in $P$ and power $PA\cdot PC=PB\cdot PD$.
(The image of a point $X$ is thus denoted by $X^*$.)

Then we have by the choice of the center and the power $A^*=C$, $B^*=D$, $C^*=A$, $D^*=B$.

The circle $(O_1)=(PAB)$ is transformed in the line $A^*B^*=CD$, and $PO_1\perp CD$.

Since $O,O_3$ are both on the perpedicular bisector of $CD$, we have $OO_3\perp CD$.

This gives $PO_1\| OO_3$.

Similarly, $PO_3\| OO_1$.

So $PO_1OO_3$ is a parallelogram, its diagonals intersect in the midpoint $Q$, say, of $OP$.

So $O_1O_3$ passes through $Q$. Similarly, $O_2O_4$ passes through $Q$.

$\square$